# Elastic Beanstalk environment variable that points to file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I understand how to set environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk, but how do I make these variables point to files of my choice?

S3, bundling the target file in my JAR, and other AWS services are all options for me.

Context: I am trying to use google-apps-clj, a Clojure library for using certain Google applications. One requirement of using [google-apps-clj](https://github.com/SparkFund/google-apps-clj) is that a JSON configuration file exists and that there is an environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) that points to it (optionally, the file could exist at ~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json without such an environment variable). My Clojure app is running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I use [lein-beanstalk](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-beanstalk) to automate some of the boring stuff.